# Convert strings to numbers with <v-edit-dialog> component in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vuetify `Datatable` with inline editing using `<v-edit-dialog>` components.

[image]

The Calories column values are numbers, but when I edit them, they are converted to strings by default and I want them to stay as numbers. For example If I change Frozen Yogurt Calories from 159 to 30, the value becomes the string "30".

[image]

**Code Snippet**

```
<td>
    <v-edit-dialog
        :return-value.sync="props.item.calories"
        lazy
        @save="save"
    > {{ props.item.calories }}
        <v-text-field
        type="number"
        slot="input"
        v-model.number="props.item.calories"
        label="Edit"
        single-line
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-edit-dialog>
</td>
```

I thought that using `v-model.number` and the `type=number` would solve the problem, but it's still happening.

This is a pen where you can reproduce my issue:

https://codepen.io/jdash99/pen/dQJVwx?editors=1010

Comment: Is there a reason for using `.sync` modifier?

Comment: I'm confused. When I edit them, they're still being saved as numbers? Was this fixed already?

Comment: @Traxo it's part of the example in the vuetify docs. I don't really know what it does... [data table docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#introduction)

Comment: Does it work for you if you remove `.sync` modifier? Any side effects?

Comment: Edit. Can confirm removing `.sync` fixes the issue.

Comment: @SnakeyHips Thanks. Please if someone has time, see with devs if this will be changed, or if sync is needed for some cases (or remove from docs if not needed)? I have no time to dig into this, but I presume it's not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model.number` changes it to number correctly, but something else changes it back to string, probably `.sync` modifier.
Remove `.sync` modifier from `:return-value.sync` and it should work.

Comment: it works, but I hope someone can explain why the number changes to string again.

Comment: I would also like to know this... seems like a bug